# How can I insert the importRange function and prevent the values from changing after implementation?

Tags: google-apps-script, importrange

I have the following code below and **want to prevent the values from changing after implementation of the importRange function**! I already tried setValue (), but it still changes. The code works fine apart from that problem. Do you have any ideas?

```
function Evaluation() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("SheetEvaluation");
  var newSheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:AX80");
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
    var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    newSheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  newSheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('=ImportRange("LINK"; "Evaluation!A1:AX80")')
  .setValue('=ImportRange("LINK"; "Evaluation!A1:AX80")');
  chart = chart.modify()
  .asComboChart()
  .addRange(newSpreadsheet.getRange('B48:AX77'))
  .addRange(newSpreadsheet.getRange('B78:AX78'))
  .addRange(newSpreadsheet.getRange('B40:AX40'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'absolute')
  .setOption('series.1.type', 'LineChart')
  .setOption('series.2.type', 'LineChart')
  .setOption('series.3.type', 'LineChart')
  .setOption('series.4.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.5.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.6.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.7.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.8.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.9.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.10.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.11.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.12.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.13.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.14.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.15.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.16.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.17.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.18.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.19.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.20.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.21.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.22.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.23.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.24.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.25.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.26.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.27.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.28.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('height', 505)
  .setOption('width', 817)
  .setPosition(1, 3, 116, 4)
  .build(); 
  newSheet.insertChart(chart);
};
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: After setting the importRange formula, getDisplayValues() and set those values in the sheet.

Comment: how is the code for this @casper ?

Comment: what do you mean by "set those values in the sheet" ?

Comment: When you set the import range, it fills the sheet. So by using [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) you can acquire the values it actually shows (so you get values instead of the formula). When you then set these display values as values in the sheet, you make the dynamic data static. Hence, it won't change anymore.

Comment: ok and can you show me an example how to set up my new code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Sheets you can have dynamic and static values.

On the Apps Script and API side you can fetch these values by:

- formula - Dynamic value
- value - Static Value
- display value - The "Static" version of a value.

In your case you want to preserve the value of a formula on a certain point in time. To do this, you will want the "static" version of those values to be saved.

You need to use [`getDisplayValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) to get the value that will be shown (not the formula) and then set your values to those with [`setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

Here is some sample code:

```
function freezeImportRange() {
  var importRangeUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11lx7OPRXTV9xwqhCVcFPcpL43glyy_9y-PPIC1ADzhk/edit#gid=0";
  var importRangeA1 = "Sheet1!A:C";


  var importedValues = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(importRangeUrl).getRange(importRangeA1).getDisplayValues();

  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("New Sheet");
  var ss = newSheet.getSheetByName(newSheet.getSheets()[0].getName());

  ss.getRange(1, 1, importedValues.length, importedValues[0].length).setValues(importedValues);

}
```

Comment: It works, but u forgot the chart function? how would it look with var chart?

Comment: it works fine, but u forgot the chart, that has to be inserted! How would that look like? If you get it right, I can mark your answer as correct! :)

Comment: You can use the same logic from your answer to insert your chart.

Comment: That does not work :( it inserts a chart in the old sheet but not in the new sheet!

Comment: @greenster10 this seems to be a new question. Your question "How can I insert the importRange function and prevent the values from changing after implementation?" was answered.